# Merge the multipage tiff in subfolder to another output folder as single image

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, imagemagick, tiff

Iam trying to merge the multipage tiff in subfolder to another output folder as single image.
the base command is convert f:\input*.tif f:\output\image1.tif

My question : Iam getting no output. What went wrong

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define input and output base folders
set BaseInputDir=F:\Images\input\
set BaseOutputDir=F:\Images\output\

rem Look for all TIF files under inoput folder (and subfolders)
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /a /s /b /a-d "%BaseInputDir%\*.tif"') do (
    
    rem Build output subfolder path
    set OutputDir=%%~dpF
    set OutputDir=!OutputDir:%BaseInputDir%=%BaseOutputDir%!

    rem If output subfolder does not exist create it
    if not exist "!OutputDir!" md "!OutputDir!"

    rem Log that we are converting this file
    ECHO Converting "%%~F" to "!OutPutDir!%%~nF.tif"

    rem Do the conversion
   for /F %%i in ("%%~F") do convert %%i "%BaseInputDir%\*.tif" "!OutPutDir!%%~nF.tif"

)
```

Comment: "getting no output" does the `echo` not emit something, or do you mean `convert` does nothing? what do you see if you change `convert` to `echo`

Comment: Hi, I tried with echo, but the screen disappears. Seems to be some logical code error,

Comment: Hi, I tried with echo, but the screen disappears. Seems to be some logical code error, When i run only the conversion logic, it do not action. It means a logical error in convert format. It should pickup the first image name in the input folder as output image name.

Comment: if you run this from `cmd` window or put `pause` at the end, of the script you should see the terminal output. This way you can see what the variables like `"!OutPutDir!%%~nF.tif"` have been expanded to.

Comment: rem Do the conversion       I realize this line of code is not working   , can you tweak it pls                                                                                             for /F %i in ("E:\INPUT\testfolder") do convert %i "E:\INPUT\testfolder\*.tif" "E:\OUTPUT\Testimage1.tif"